# Run dotnet core on Ubuntu 20.4

Tags: permissions, dotnet

I just shifted to ubuntu and I am trying to run dotnet core 3.1 project on Ubuntu.
I successfully installed dotnet core sdk.
But when i go to the folder in a separate mounted disk and run command `dotnet watch run` or `dotnet run`
it gives me an error of permission denied.
Please tell me how to fix this. I am stuck in this for about 2 days. Any help will be really really appreciated.
Please check out the attachment for error.
[error detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OU4vZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

You start the program in a "seperate mounted disk".
Question: Is that filesystem (and directories) read/writable?
.exe and dll are created?
Does "dotnet watch run" work fine when you move the project to a local disk?